# Invisible DataGridView rows are visible in several TabPages of TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabcontrol, visible

I have TabControl with several TabPage-s.
Each TabPage keeps corresponding DataGridView object
that, in turn, binded with corresponding DataTable. 
Each DataTable object is 3 columns' string table (Names, Values, Comments).
So each TabPage looks as good grid table. It is OK.
During this binding, I want to hide several rows in each tab.

```
DataFridView LoadDataToTab(ref DataTable dt, TabPage tab)
{    
    DataGridView grid   = new DataGridView();    
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource();    
    source.DataSource = dt;     
    grid.DataSource = source;    

    tab.Control.Add(grid);    
    // Now all binding is done;    

    // Now I need to hide some rows in TabPage-s:    
    HideSomeRows(ref grid);    

    return grid;    
} 

void HideSomeRows(ref DataGridView grid)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string val = grid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        // SomeString is some "xyz" stirng
        if( val == SomeString    ||
            val == SomeOtherString)
        {
            grid.Rows[i].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem: only "first" TabPage in this TabControl hides specified rows.**

- All other TabPages show all rows (don't hide any row). The "first" means,
  the first that used *HideSomeRows()* and then it is first added to
  the TabControl. I did several experiments, to bypass the first
  TabPage. Second TabPage that has become first hides rows, but
  others not.
- I checked also, using breakpoints, that all "not first" TabPages have
  Visible  false rows property, but the rows are visible!

Answer (score 0):

After several experiments together with my colleague, we found solution:
 **to select current TabPage in TabControl before hiding rows of DataGridView:**

```
    ...
    Tab.SelectedIndex = tabIndex;
    ...
    HideSomeRows(ref grid);
```

Please see the same program that changed to work correctly with addition, signed by

```
      /*!*/
```

.

```
DataFridView LoadDataToTab(ref DataTable dt, TabPage tab, TabControl Tab/*!*/, int tabIndex/*!*/)
{    
    DataGridView grid   = new DataGridView();    
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource();    
    source.DataSource = dt;     
    grid.DataSource = source;    

    tab.Control.Add(grid);    
    // Now all binding is done;  

    // This TabControl Tab has inside TabPage tab 
    Tab.SelectedIndex = tabIndex; /*!*/

    // Now I need to hide some rows in TabPage-s:    
    HideSomeRows(ref grid);    

    return grid;    
} 

void HideSomeRows(ref DataGridView grid)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string val = grid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        // SomeString is some "xyz" stirng
        if( val == SomeString    ||
            val == SomeOtherString)
        {
            grid.Rows[i].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```